# Validate img to save with JSpdf

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

i have 3 inputs to upload 3 diferent images, i want to validate if 2 of the input have uploaded image, then save as pdf, if i have just 1 can save it to pdf. This is my code of JSPdf:

```
 if(parseInt(img) === 0){
        doc.addImage('JPEG', 16,110,85,85);
        } else {
            doc.addImage(img2, 'JPEG', 110,110,85,85);
            doc.addImage(img3, 'JPEG', 16,200,85,85);
        } 

        if(parseInt(img2) === 0){
            doc.addImage('JPEG', 110,110,85,85);
        } else {
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 16,110,85,85);
            doc.addImage(img3, 'JPEG', 16,200,85,85);
        } 
        
        if(parseInt(img3) === 0){
            doc.addImage('JPEG', 16,200,85,85);
        } else {
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 16,110,85,85);
            doc.addImage(img2, 'JPEG', 110,110,85,85);
        } 

doc.save('mypdf.pdf');
```

img, img1 and img2 works if i upload the 3 images at same time but if i upload just 1 or 2 it doesn't work.

When i use this code:

```
      doc.addImage(imagen, 'JPEG', 16,110,85,85);
      doc.addImage(imagen2, 'JPEG', 110,110,85,85);
      doc.addImage(imagen3, 'JPEG', 16,200,85,85);
```

Works great but only if ai upload the 3 img at same time, if i try to upload just one or two not working.

Comment: You are missing the file handler in three places in your 1st code block. say `doc.addImage('JPEG', 16,110,85,85);` should be `doc.addImage(img,'JPEG', 16,110,85,85);`

Comment: yes i fix that, but still not working. The last code are working great but just allow me to upload the 3 images at same time, when i try to upload just one or two image in those 3 input, not work. i just want to modifi that code to permit upload one or two images if i need it. if you need more info please let me know, i will appreciate.

Comment: You can not call `addImage` without supplying image data as first parameter, that makes no sense whatsoever. I don't know what exactly your variables are supposed to contain, so I can't tell what kind of check `parseInt(img) === 0` actually performs either - but you need to call `doc.addImage` only if you _have_ any image, and if not, then for that image number/position, you simply must not call it.

Comment: I have an input to snap the image and it works but just if i snap it all img at same time